# python Slicing a file with a line (a phrase) rather than a character

Tags: python, slice

i looked up the slicing documentation and still have not found what i need. I am a beginner.

I have a big textfile. I want to slice that file using a recurring identical line within the document. Take what it is 2 of those lines and save it in a numerated file)

I think i can get my loop for saving to work, but i have no idea how to slice the document.

Something like :

```
    for i in xrange(n):
    f = open("patent.data_"+str(i)+".dat","w")
```

i thought that when i extract the parts of the file, i simply let a counter run with it (n).

Can someone provide me with help or a link so i can figure this out ?

Best wishes

PS:  here is my updated non working solution :

```
    f = open(PATENTS, 'r')
text =f.read()
text.split("\n "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"\n")
```

Ok, i tried it with .splitlines and i think i am a lot closer to a working solution for splitting the text into the chunks that i want. Here is what i got so far and works :

```
f = open(PATENTS, 'r')
text =f.read()
n=0
counter=0
textblock=[]
stext= text.splitlines()

for lines in stext:
    if stext[n]!='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
        textblock.append(stext[n])

    else:
        counter+=1
    n+=1
print counter
print textblock
f.close()
```

The counter gives me out the correct number of textchunks i want to get, and the if statement works too. What does not work unfortunately is indexing the variable textblock. I thought of something like :

```
textblock[counter]
```

But that gives me an error "list index out of range"

Ok switched to a list of tuples like this: but now dont know how to acess the tuple values inside the list :(

```
for lines in stext:
    if stext[n]!='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
        textblock.append((counter,stext[n]))

    else:
        counter+=1
    n+=1
print counter
```

Comment: Your "non-working solution" is a syntax error! You can't embed double quotes inside a double-quoted string. No idea what you're actually using, but try this: `'\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'`. Make it _exactly_ like in your file or it will not work.

Comment: Please only paste in code that you have actually tried out, otherwise you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I tried exactly what you proposed : text.split('\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n').  That just gives me the variable text that i can index to get every single character. But onfortunately does not split the text into chunks :(

Comment: Then your file does not contain this exact character sequence.

Comment: Warm up by splitting on a smaller string, e.g., `text.split("<?xml")`. Then figure out what you're doing wrong. Without inspecting your file, nobody else can do it for you.

Comment: I know i am a total noob but i seriously try :( Found the .splitlines command and i am gonna update my code and hopefully i am close :)

Comment: Stephan, `splitlines` will complicate your code down the line, and you'll still have to match against the lines you want. But by all means give it a try... maybe the problem is related to the newlines and it will mysteriously work now. Good luck!

Comment: You're counting the chunks, but `textblock` contains a flat list of all the lines you saved-- they are not chunked. But if the `<?xml ...` line works, use it with my answer and you'll have your chunks and simpler program structure.

Comment: Tried something different. Sorry i get confused easily. Tried it with a list of tuples.... as posted above. Now i dont know how to acess them in the list :(

Comment: Stephan, it's fine if you don't want to understand my answer, but this is not the place to solve every problem you come against as you explore different approaches. Seriously, my suggestion is that you should go work through a python tutorial on lists-- I mean this in the best way: You're struggling in the dark like this, you'll learn more by following a tutorial. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from itertools import count
c = count(1)
with open("mainfile.txt") as f:
    temp = []
    filenum = next(c)
    for i in f:
        if i in temp:
            temp = []
            filenum = next(c)
        temp.append(i)
        with open("patent.data_"+str(filenum)+".dat","a") as f1:
            f1.write(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The python term for what you want is "splitting", not slicing. Since your split pattern is an entire line, read the whole file into a string and split it into a list of chunks like this:

```
fp = open("pattern_data.txt")
text = fp.read()
fp.close()
parts = text.split('\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
```

`parts` is now a list of your file chunks.

Note that `split()` removes the splitting text from the results; that should be ok since you know where it was. Also, the way I wrote it the cut lines must *exactly* contain the split pattern, and nothing else (remove the newlines `\n` if there might be extra space at the end of the line, or if this fails to work). If you ever need a split pattern that can vary somewhat, use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) which splits on regular expressions instead of a fixed string.

Comment: Thank you. i think i understand and searched the web for examples. Still mine does not work :(      f = open(PATENTS, 'r')
    text =f.read()
    text.split("\n "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"\n")

Comment: "Does not work" is not going to get you a lot of help! But the code you pasted contains double quotes inside double quotes, which is a syntax error. Try `split('\n "...')`. And is there really a space before the `<?xml`? You must match the sequence of characters _exactly_. Also check about Windows vs. unix line endings, etc.